Initialize the select2 in dynamic form in alpinejs
I've spent hours and hours on how I initialize the select2 on alpinejs in dynamic form.

I have an html file with a select tag and Add button
I initialize the select to be a select2

(Expected) When I click the Add button it will add another select form. That also should initialize as select 2
(Actual) : When I click the Add button it does not initialized as select2
I've tried every time I that I click the Add button it will trigger the initializeSelect2
It does work, but on 2nd to the last select form does not work
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div
            x-data="{
        count: 1,
        selects: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
        toggle() { this.count++; initSelect2() }
    }"
        >
            <button @click="toggle()">Add</button>

            <template x-for="i in count" :key="i">
                <select id="" name="" class="select2 form-control">
                    <template x-for="(select, index) in selects" :key="index">
                        <option value="" x-text="select"></option>
                    </template>
                </select>
            </template>
        </div>
        <script>
            function initSelect2()
            {
                $(".select2").select2();
            }
            $(document).ready(function () {
                initSelect2();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Playground Link

You must wait that Alpine has updated the DOM before applying the Select2, to do this we can use the magic method $nextTick:
toggle() { this.count++; $nextTick(() => initSelect2()) }


You're smarter than AI buddy, $nextTick was all it took.
